# Is IO an instance of Functor just because it is a Monad in the first place?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, io-monad, do-notation

From [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) I understand that the `do` notation is just syntactic sugar for monadic style; and from the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) I read more or less the same; so my understanding is that there can't be any `do` notation if there's no `Monad` instance.

Yet I read this definition of the `Functor` instance of the `IO` type ctor.

```hs
instance Functor IO where  
    fmap f action = do  
        result <- action  
        return (f result)
```

which is just syntactic sugar for the following, isn't it?

```hs
instance Functor IO where  
    fmap f action = action >>= return . f
```

which implies the underling assumption the `IO` is instance of `Monad` first; and this come against that fact that every `Monad` is a `Functor` and not the other way around.

In fact, I had absorbed that a `Monad` is "something more than" an `Applicative`, which is in turn "something more than" a `Functor`, which goes together with `Applicative`'s definition enforcing the `Functor` constraint on its instances (and `Monad`'s definition ideally requiring that its instances are `Applicative`s, as in *don't make it a `Monad` if it's not an `Applicative`*).

In other words, the code above makes me think that there would be no way to write the `Functor` instance for `IO`, if `IO` was not a `Monad` in the first place.

And now that I think about it, maybe this is just like saying that `IO` was created as a full-fledged `Monad`, and the instance above was later made just for completeness and mathematical consistency.

But I'm confused, and so I seek for help here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A type having an instance of `Monad` implies it must have a definition of `Functor` (and `Applicative`), but that doesn’t mean the `Functor` instance must be defined “first”, only that both instances must exist. As long as the method implementations aren’t defined in terms of each other circularly, there’s no problem.

In fact, it often makes sense to implement `Monad` for a type first, then define `Applicative` and `Functor` mechanically in terms of `Monad` operations, because `Monad` is more powerful, so the other instances are just *restrictions* of the `Monad` instance:

```
-- These work for any T with a Monad instance.

instance Functor T where
  fmap f x = do
    x' <- x
    return (f x')

instance Applicative T where
  pure = return
  f <*> x = do
    f' <- f
    x' <- x
    return (f' x')
```

This is precisely *because* “a `Monad` is ‘something more than’ an `Applicative`, which is in turn ‘something more than’ a `Functor`”.

It’s also worth noting that originally, the `Monad` and `Functor` classes were unrelated, and the `Applicative` class (added later) was as well. There were separate equivalent functions for each, like `fmap`, `liftA`, and `liftM`; `pure` and `return`; `(<*>)` and `ap`; `traverse` and `mapM`. Conventionally you would write a `Monad` instance and implement the other classes in terms of that. These separate definitions still exist, but are now redundant: since the “Applicative–Monad Proposal” made `Applicative` a superclass of `Monad`, and `Functor` of `Applicative`, you can *always* use e.g. `pure` instead of `return` or `traverse` instead of `mapM`, since they’re the same functions, but work in strictly more contexts. So there’s also some historical context as to why there might be separate definitions of these instances for a type.

As @dfeuer points out, there are some data structures where `mapM` (`mapM_`, `forM`, `forM_`) is more efficient than `traverse` (resp. `traverse_`, `for`, `for_`), such as `Data.Vector` types. In the specific case of vectors, I believe this is because the library can take advantage of monadic sequencing as an optimisation, to enable more streaming and allocating results in place. But they are equivalent, in that `traverse` should always produce the same result.

Comment: +1. So when you write that _other instances are just_ restrictions _of the `Monad` instance_, you mean that there is a way to use the tools a `Monad` instance provides (e.g. `>>=` and `return`, or alternatively the `do` notation) to write instances of the other two, but not the other way around, for instance there's no way I can make a type ctor an instance of `Monad` just relying on `fmap` and/or `<*>` and `pure`. Is this correct?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: Correct! In particular, `Monad` gives you monadic application `(=<<) :: (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b`, where the `f` effects of the first operand can depend on the *value* of the `a` result from the second operand. You can’t do that with `Applicative` application `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, because the `f` effects of the two operands are *independent*: the first operand must produce a pure function, and the `f` effects have *already happened* before that function is applied to an argument.

Comment: Accepted the answer as it fully convinces me. But I've not quite got you'r last comment about `Monad` vs `Applicative` as regards the `flip`ping. Maybe I have to sleep on it a bit.

Comment: There are some unusual cases where `mapM` can be more efficient than `traverse`. The one I know about in the wild is in `vector`. The monadic streaming framework can do magic tricks for `mapM` that aren't available for `traverse`.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: I used `=<<` instead of `>>=` for illustration, to draw an analogy with function application: `($)`, `(<*>)`, and `(=<<)` are all kinds of application. As a rule of thumb, in `f $ x`, `f` and `x` are pure (although `f` may return an effectful computation, as in `putStrLn $ "hello"`); in `f <*> x`, `f` and `x` are effectful, but the effects are independent, and only the *result* of the function may depend on the value of the argument; and in `f =<< x`, again both are effectful, but the *effects* of the function may also depend on the argument value.

Comment: @dfeuer sure you don't have that backwards? There definitely are cases where `vector` performs better with the _applicative_ instead of monadic interface, because in that case the shapes can be precalculated before looking at any values.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm not sure how well the monadic fusion stuff works in practice, but `mapM` is designed to slot into that. The vector gets turned into a stream over whatever `Monad` is in play, and `mapM` operates streamishly on that.